XAML with Google MLKit camera view get stuck in InitializeComponent
I have an Android app which uses CameraView from BarcodeScanner.Mobile;assembly=BarcodeScanner.Mobile.Maui namespace.
In some devices, when trying to open de camera, after allowing to use it, the app get stuck.
This is the XAML constructor:
public CaptureCardPage(CaptureCardViewModel viewModel)
{
    try
    {
        BarcodeScanner.Mobile.Methods.SetSupportBarcodeFormat(BarcodeFormats.QRCode | BarcodeFormats.Pdf417);

        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = captureCardModel = viewModel;

        Shell.SetTabBarIsVisible(this, false);

        allowed = BarcodeScanner.Mobile.Methods.AskForRequiredPermission().Result;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}

When debugging in a real device, app get stuck at InitializeComponent(). Unfortunately, I cannot debug inside, but if I navigate to the implementación, I see this:
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    global::Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml(this, typeof(CaptureCardPage));
    SoundFailure = global::Microsoft.Maui.Controls.NameScopeExtensions.FindByName<global::CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views.MediaElement>(this, "SoundFailure");
    SoundSuccess = global::Microsoft.Maui.Controls.NameScopeExtensions.FindByName<global::CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views.MediaElement>(this, "SoundSuccess");
    cameraView = global::Microsoft.Maui.Controls.NameScopeExtensions.FindByName<global::BarcodeScanner.Mobile.CameraView>(this, "cameraView");
    ManualButton = global::Microsoft.Maui.Controls.NameScopeExtensions.FindByName<global::Microsoft.Maui.Controls.StackLayout>(this, "ManualButton");
    AllowedMessage = global::Microsoft.Maui.Controls.NameScopeExtensions.FindByName<global::Microsoft.Maui.Controls.StackLayout>(this, "AllowedMessage");
    DeniedMessage = global::Microsoft.Maui.Controls.NameScopeExtensions.FindByName<global::Microsoft.Maui.Controls.StackLayout>(this, "DeniedMessage");
    aiLayout = global::Microsoft.Maui.Controls.NameScopeExtensions.FindByName<global::Microsoft.Maui.Controls.StackLayout>(this, "aiLayout");
    Waiting = global::Microsoft.Maui.Controls.NameScopeExtensions.FindByName<global::Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ActivityIndicator>(this, "Waiting");
    lblValidating = global::Microsoft.Maui.Controls.NameScopeExtensions.FindByName<global::Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Label>(this, "lblValidating");
}

And the only strange thing I see in the output windows is:

Loaded assembly:
/data/data/com.desytec.daccess/files/.override/System.Collections.Specialized.dll
[External] [desytec.daccess] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed
26800(1645KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free,
7223KB/14MB, paused 143us,144us total 65.204ms [InputTransport] Input
channel destroyed: 'ClientS', fd=110 [OpenGLRenderer] setSurface
called with nullptr [OpenGLRenderer] setSurface called with nullptr
Thread finished:  #12 El subproceso 12 terminó con código
0 (0x0). El subproceso 14 terminó con código 0 (0x0). Thread finished:
 #14 [libc] Requested dump for pid 28748
(desytec.daccess)

Any help to solve the problem, please?
